# Porque al hacer scroll desde el móvil la imagen se mueve aún teniendo la propiedad background-attachment: fixed;

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

quisiera me pudieran ayudar con este tema, estoy practicanto html y css muy simple, he puesto una imagen de fondo y le puse la propiedad background-attachment: fixed; y hasta donde leí es para que la imagen quede estática y no se mueva al hacer scroll.
Desde la web todo funciona de maravilla, pero cuando se abre desde el móvil al hacer scroll la imagen se mueve un poco mostrando un fondo blanco pero luego se ajusta nuevamente. Alguien me podría indicar si esto es normal por el navegador o si es que me falta algo por hacer estas son las siguientes propiedades que tengo actualmente:

```
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(./img/fondo-hamburguesa.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

También dejo el proyecto publicado
https://maguz727.github.io/menu-simple-restaurante/

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Parece normal de Google Chrome al menos y no se si tenga solución. Si prestas atención, ese efecto sucede cuando llegas al punto en que la barra superior del navegador se oculta.

Comment: Mientras tanto, una forma de disimularlo es con un `background-color` similar al de la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta es que algunos navegadores de móviles toman el

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

como

```
background-attachment: scroll;
```

Para solucionarlo te sugiero colocarle un  `<div>` adicional y aplicar estilos a ese elemento en lugar del fondo del `body` quedando de esta forma:

El CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(./img/fondo-hamburguesa.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

y el HTML:

```
<div class="background-image"></div>

<div class="content">
  
</div>
```